# How do I investigate read timeouts when connected to one DC?

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with two dc's, recently in one dc(DC1) I'm seeing timeout error as below.

```
Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
```

Since timeouts were very frequent, I have switched dc (DC2) and application is working fine without any timeout errors. In DC1, I could see some nodes with bad disk which I had removed out the cluster. The logs in DC1 and DC2 seem to be same except for the below in DC1. Could you please let me know why I'm I facing timeouts in only one DC and below javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset error.

Please let me know if there is any recommendation to address this issue.

Error message is from DC1 nodes and x.x.x.x are the different nodes in DC2

```
ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/x.x.x.x] 2024-02-08 16:15:20,281 CassandraDaemon.java:244 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/x.x.x.x,5,main]
java.io.IOError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/x.x.x.x] 2024-02-08 16:15:20,281 CassandraDaemon.java:244 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/x.x.x.x,5,main]
java.io.IOError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/x.x.x.x] 2024-02-08 16:15:20,281 CassandraDaemon.java:244 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/x.x.x.x,5,main]
java.io.IOError: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really not a lot to go on in your post other than replicas are unresponsive and it could be due to a lot of factors such as slow disks, busy CPU, slow network, etc.

In order to troubleshoot your issue, you need to start with the application logs specifically looking at the errors the driver reported. The full error message and the full stacktrace will provide you clues as to what is going on.

The clues that you gleaned from the application logs will determine the next step in your investigation. Cheers!